# Intercept IP address or Domain Name from safari using VPN

Tags: ios, vpn, networkextension

Hello I am working on an application which can intercept the visited network traffic ip address list from iPhone (similar to Charles Proxy).

Currently I have written code to create a VPN profile using **NETunnelProviderManager** class.

```
        NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences { [weak self] managers, error in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if self.manager != managers?.first {
                self.manager = managers?.first
            } else {
                self.manager = self.makeManager()
            }
            self.manager?.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error in saving VPN Config: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                self.manager?.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        do {
                            try self.manager?.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                        } catch let vpnTunnelError {
                            print("Unable to start VPN Tunnel by error: \(vpnTunnelError.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Load From Preference Error")
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

```
    private func makeManager() -> NETunnelProviderManager {
        let manager = NETunnelProviderManager()
        manager.localizedDescription = "NetworkTrafficVPN"

        let proto = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
        proto.providerBundleIdentifier = "com.NetworkTraffic.vpn-tunnel"
        proto.serverAddress = "Network Traffic"
        manager.protocolConfiguration = proto

        let onDemandRule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
        onDemandRule.interfaceTypeMatch = .any
        manager.isOnDemandEnabled = true
        manager.onDemandRules = [onDemandRule]
        manager.isEnabled = true
        return manager
    }
```

Once I start the vpn tunnel (**self.manager?.connection.startVPNTunnel()**) from the created **NETunnelProviderManager** object

I get a callback in **NEPacketTunnelProvider** network extension method (**startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)**).

I have created the **NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings** inside **startTunnel()** method using the assigned IP address of the iPhone.

After calling the method **self.setTunnelNetworkSettings(settings) { error in }** I am getting network data callback inside
**self.packetFlow.readPackets { (data, numbers) }** method

```
class PacketTunnelProvider: NEPacketTunnelProvider {

    // MARK: - Constants

    let logger: Logger = Logger(subsystem: "NetworkTrafficSubsystem", category: "NetworkTrafficCategory")
    let proxyServerPort: Int = 8888
    let proxyServerAddress = "192.168.43.185" // Device assigned ip address

    // MARK: - NEPacketTunnelProvider

    override func startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        let settings = NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings(tunnelRemoteAddress: proxyServerAddress)
        settings.tunnelOverheadBytes = 80
        settings.mtu = 1400

        settings.ipv4Settings = NEIPv4Settings(addresses: [proxyServerAddress], subnetMasks: ["255.255.255.255"])
        settings.ipv4Settings?.includedRoutes = [NEIPv4Route.default()]
        settings.ipv4Settings?.excludedRoutes = []
        settings.dnsSettings = NEDNSSettings(servers: ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"])
        settings.dnsSettings?.matchDomains = []
        self.setTunnelNetworkSettings(settings) { error in
            if let e = error {
                self.logger.info("Settings error")
                completionHandler(e)
            } else {
                self.logger.info("Settings set without error")
                self.readPacketObjects()
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    private func readPacketObjects() {

        self.packetFlow.readPackets { (data, numbers) in
            self.logger.info("Inside readPackets completionHandler")
            // Way to print the ip address from the received data array
            self.packetFlow.writePackets(data, withProtocols: numbers)
            self.readPacketObjects()
        }
    }
}
```

But I am unable to decode the data object from **self.packetFlow.readPackets { (data, numbers) in }** method.

So my question is that in order to read the IP address of all the visited network traffic is this the correct approach or I need to do something else.

If this is correct approach then let me know how to decode the received **Data** object.
If not then please suggest the correct way to achieve this functionality.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: The `numbers` array indicates the packet types in the `data` array (you would expect AF_INET and AF_INET6).  You would then need to decode the data to access the IP address from the packet header https://thirdinternet.com/ipv4-packet-structure/

Comment: @Paulw11 I am able to differentiate the incoming packets via AF_INET, but is there a way to decode the incoming data object to reveal IP address or domain name

Comment: You can determine the IP address. You will need to write the code to parse the header data.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is that in order to read the IP address of all the visited network traffic is this the correct approach or I need to do something else

You need to implement **[Per App VPN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager)**.

Per App VPN can be implemented for Supervised Devices only. if you want to implement it in test mode apple provides [Testing Per App VPN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager) (last paragraph of this page) which works without MDM.